# In Pandas, how do I check if three combined string columns == 10 characters, and if so, insert into new column?

Tags: python, string, pandas, substring, string-length

I'm wanting to combine three Pandas string columns into a new column, if the new column's total combined characters equal 10.

If not equal to 10, then check next combined column.

I've tried adding the columns together into a new column if Phone1Area equals 3 string characters, and if Phone1Prefix equals 3 string characters, and if Phone1NumberPart equals 4 string characters, in other words ten total characters. I've tried adding columns if they are 3+3+4 characters, df.loc, and many more things.

Here is a sample of the data set:

[image: Dataset]

Here is the code:

```
dfp['p1'] = df[(df['Phone1Area'].str.len() == 3.0)]['Phone1Area'] + 
df[(df['Phone1Exchange'].str.len() == 3.0)]['Phone1Exchange'] + 
df[(df['Phone1NumberPart'].str.len() == 4.0)]['Phone1NumberPart']


dfp['p2'] = df[(df['Phone2Area'].str.len() == 3.0)]['Phone2Area'] + 
df[(df['Phone2Exchange'].str.len() == 3.0)]['Phone2Exchange'] + 
df[(df['Phone2NumberPart'].str.len() == 4.0)]['Phone2NumberPart']

df_phone.loc[df_phone['p1'].str.len() == 10, 'phone'] = df_phone['p1']
df_phone.loc[df_phone['p2'].str.len() == 10, 'phone'] = df_phone['p2']
```

Here is what I want it to do, but in Pandas:

```
if df_phone['p1'].str.len() == 10:
    then insert df_phone['p1'] into df_phone['phone']
elif df_phone['p2'].str.len() == 10:
    then insert df_phone['p2'] into df_phone['phone']
elif df_phone['p3'].str.len() == 10:
    then insert df_phone['p3'] into df_phone['phone']
```

I expected the phone column to have the 10 characters from phone 1, and if that wasn't 10 characters, then the phone column to have the 10 characters from phone 2, etc.

But one of the results was:

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'str'
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Please post some sample of your dataset

Comment: Ok, I just posted some sample data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help:

```
df['phone'] = ''
df['test_phone'] = df['phone1Area'] + df['phone1Exchange'] + df['phone1NumberPart']
df['phone'][df['test_phone'].str.len() == 10] = df['test_phone']
df['test_phone'] = df['phone2Area'] + df['phone2Exchange'] + df['phone2NumberPart']
df['phone'][(df['test_phone'].str.len() == 10) & (df['phone'] == '')] = df['test_phone']
df['test_phone'] = df['phone3Area'] + df['phone3Exchange'] + df['phone3NumberPart']
df['phone'][(df['test_phone'].str.len() == 10) & (df['phone'] == '')] = df['test_phone']
etc.
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm still running test to check the code, but so far it looks right! What is it doing different than the code I was using?

Comment: Happy to hear :) There might be some other things, but the most significant thing I see is the format `if df_phone['p1'].str.len() == 10: then... elif... else...`, which is the way to make conditions in plain python, but not in Pandas, where you need to make the comparisons element-wise, and not for the series object as one object.

Comment: In: df['phone'][(df['test_phone'].str.len() == 10) & (df['phone'] == '') = df['test_phone'], does 'test_phone' insert into 'phone' where 'phone' meets the (string length) & (blank string) criteria? Is that how that part works?

Comment: It checks: 1) That in `test phone` there is a 10 digits string, 2) That there isn't already a 10 digits string in `phone`, and if so, insert to `phone` what is in `test_phone`

Comment: It looks like it's only inserting Phone 1 strings.

Comment: @uncoded0123 If phone1 meets the criterias, than this is what would be inserted. Only if not, the other phones are checked. Just like the `if... elif... elif...` structure in your code. Were you expecting something else?

Comment: I've checked the data multiple times, and it looks like the code works when I run the code twice. But, if it's run just once, it only inserts 'phone1' into 'phone'. I've checked the data, and that's what it shows, do you know how to fix that? Thanks

Comment: I don't think it had something to do with it, but in my code I was missing "]" in lines 5 and 7. Added them now. See if that helps.  If not, I would need to see some samples of lines on which my code doesn't work well, with code sample. Maybe as an edited question here or as a new question.

Comment: There are some minor things I didn't put in the question on Stack Overflow. I think your answer is working for the way I wrote the question. But I was wanting it to first read the Areas, Exchanges, and NumberParts from one Data Frame named DF_FILE, without editing it. Then, to do all the column creation and data insertion in another data frame named df_out1. How would I modify it to do that, I tried to figure it out, but when I edit it, it takes running the code twice. I'm not sure why. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Another solution using `np.select` that should be faster:

```
conditions = [df_phone['p1'].str.len() == 10, df_phone['p2'].str.len() == 10,\
              df_phone['p3'].str.len() == 10]
choices = [df_phone['p1'], df_phone['p2'], df_phone['p3']]

df_phone['phone'] = np.select(conditions, choices, default = '')
```

> Documentation:
>
> - [np.select](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html): pick the choice for the first `True` value encountered in conditions. If only `False`, fill with `default`.

Comment: SmileyPod, Thanks. It looks like a lot of it works, but I checked the data, and it didn't show the first string with length 10 (from the file I'm using, which was 'p2' in this case). Do you know how to fix it? Thanks

Comment: @uncoded0123 -  Can you give me the sample so that I understand what you mean ?